# Failure scenarios of RavenDB cluster - ParallelShardAccessStrategy

Tags: cluster-computing, ravendb, sharding

I have read articles about failure scenarios of RavenDB cluster (http://ayende.com/blog/155937/api-design-sharding-status-for-failure-scenarios-solving-at-the-right-granularity) which were very helpful. However, the solution only works with SequentialShardAccessStrategy, or at least I was not able to get it work with ParallelShardAccessStrategy. :o) Is there a way for ParallelShardAccessStrategy?

Comment: shardStrategy = new ShardStrategy(shardStores)
   .ShardingOn<Sample>(s => s.Author);

shardStrategy.ShardAccessStrategy = new SequentialShardAccessStrategy(); 
shardStrategy.ShardAccessStrategy.OnError += (failingCommands, requestData, exception) => { 
   if (requestData.Query == null) return false; 
   return true; 
   };

Comment: The code above works well but when I change SequentialShardAccessStrategy for ParallelShardAccessStrategy I get error (from ParallelShardAccessStrategy.cs - unknown since I use nuget reference).